# Angular Directive Replace

Tags: angularjs

Can someone please tell me why the following directive doesn't work?

```
angular.module('app',[]).
directive('Test',function() {
  return {
    restrict : 'E',
    replace : true,
    template :'<h3>Test Test Test Test</h3>'
    };
  });
```

Html

```
 <body ng-app="app">
    <Test></Test>
  </body>
```

If i understand correctly i expect it to display `Test Test Test Test` inside an h3 , but it doesn't, any idea why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure why but if you name your directive `directive('test',function() {` it works.

Comment: it did, that is strange

Comment: nvm http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive they mention it here in directive matching